# Disable 'hold' circle from wacom tablet in Photoshop CC 2020 without losing pen pressure functionality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, drawing-tablet

I have a Wacom Bamboo Fun tablet.      In Photoshop CC 2020 if I hold the pen down in one place for too long a circle forms and the pen cursor doesn't move until the circle is complete.  It is quite annoying and gets in the way of using the pen properly.

I have found that if I disable 'Use Windows Ink' in the Wacom tablet properties this problem goes away, but so also does pen pressure functionality.

I have also tried another suggestion found via google which is to disable 'Show visual effects' in the Windows Ink settings but this makes no difference.  I have tried the other settings there enabled and disabled one by one but nothing makes a difference.

Is there a way to remove this annoying circle behavior without losing pen pressure functionality in Photoshop CC 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To turn off the circle thing, open `Control Panel` and navigate to `Hardware and Sound`, then `Change Pen Tablet Settings`

   [image]

   Then `Pen Action` > `Press and Hold` > `Settings` > turn off `Enable Press and Hold`. This will turn off the circle thing, but you still are going to get modifier keys under cursor, slowdowns and sometimes freezes — those are bugs of Windows Ink inside Photoshop.
2. If you're turning off `Windows Ink`, you need specify a different tablet driver for Photoshop — Wintab. For that

   - go to `%appdata%\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Adobe Photoshop 2020 Settings`
   - create a new text file `PSUserConfig.txt` there
   - put this line in it: `UseSystemStylus 0`
   - restart Photoshop

   note that Adobe is going to abandon Wintab soon and if you're using the latest PS version (2020.1) there are already bugs in it because of that.

Comment: Thankyou.  I did indeed still get some freezes after disabling press and hold, but turning off Windows Ink using the config file did work.   I don't know if I'm imagining it but the responsiveness and accuracy feels ever so slightly better with Windows Ink enabled (UseSystemStylus 1),  I will spend some time to see what I can get used to.